# Build a "About Me" GUI page in Java

Tags: java

I am doing a GUI application, and now building the "About Me" page of the GUI. This "About Me" should contain introduction about myself and also a picture of me. Below are the codes I did:

```
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class ContactMe extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
    JPanel panelTop = new JPanel(); // new GUI components
    JButton butAboutMe = new JButton("About Me...");
    JButton butOpenFile = new JButton("Open File...");

// ...
    BufferedImage orgImg; // image of opened file

    ContactMe()
    { // A No-Argument Constructor
        setTitle ( "MyName Image Viewer X" ); //...
    }

    void initGUI()
    {
        panelTop.add(butOpenFile); //add buttons and slider to top JPanel
        panelTop.add(butAboutMe);
        add(panelTop, BorderLayout.NORTH); //add JPanel to top of JFrame
        add(butOpenFile, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(sPImg, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(labelStatus, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
// registering this class object as event listener for the Button
        butOpenFile.addActionListener(this);
// EVENT HANLDING below, with Anonymous Class approach:
// register a new listener object (of an anonymous class) to Button
        butAboutMe.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
// show AboutMe Message Dialog window
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
        "Members(left to right):\n" +
        "MyName(ME)\n CHAN Tai Man\n CHAN Siu Man",
        "About Me: G22m2, 2019-2020, OOP",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
        new ImageIcon("AboutMe.jpg"));
        } });
    }
//...
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { // Method to start program
        (new Contact()).setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("END of main() method!");
    }
}
```

Error 1:

```
error: Main is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
public class ContactMe extends JFrame implements ActionListener
```

Error 2:

```
error: cannot find symbol sPImg
add(sPImg, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Error 3:

```
error: cannot find symbol labelStatus
 add(labelStatus, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

However I have got three errors and cannnot solve it, I really need some help and hints. Thank You !!

Comment: Did you copy/paste this code from somewhere? Nowhere in your code I can see any variable creation of a `sPImg` or `labelStatus`.

Comment: Why does `ContactMe` implement `ActionListener` interface? If you really want to do that you have to override the `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: The last two are simple: you don't have anything named `sPImg` or `labelStatus` in your class, so it doesn't know what you are talking about. Either define something like that or remove the offending lines of code. The first one means you must implement the `actionPerformed` method if you claim to implement `ActionListener`. Since you provide an action listener as an anonymous inner class,  you can probably just remove the `implement ActionListener` in your class definition.

Comment: You use an anonymous class for your ActionListener needs, I don't think implementing `ActionListener` is what you wanted.

Comment: In general, error msgs tell you exactly what is wrong with the code: `actionPerformed` is not implemented, variable `sPImg` and `labelStatus` are missing.

Answer (score 0):

## How to fix your errors

### Error 1:  Main is not abstract and does not override abstract method ...

> When an abstract class is subclassed, the subclass usually provides
> implementations for all of the abstract methods in its parent class.
> However, if it does not, then the subclass must also be declared
> abstract.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.htm

This means you must provide your own implementation of the method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`.

### Errors 2 and 3: cannot find symbol

You did not declare the variables `sPImg` and `labelStatus`. You need to define any variable that you want to use in Java.